# How to display message on successfully deleting record from mysql in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am deleting from a table but I am unable to set message on delete

Here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $row_array = $_POST['post'];
    $row_ids = implode(', ', $row_array);
    $delete_sql = "DELETE from $table_name WHERE id IN ($row_ids)";
    $delete_result = $wpdb->get_results($delete_sql);
    var_dump($delete_result);
    if($delete_result) {
            $message = count($row_ids) . " submission deleted.";
    }
}


<?php
    if(isset($message)) {
    ?>
    <div id="message" class="updated notice is-dismissible"><p><?php echo $message; ?> </p><button type="button" class="notice-dismiss"><span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss this notice.</span></button></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($delete_result);` shows what?

Comment: it shows array(0) { }

Comment: Empty array is considered `false`, that's why `$message` never set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_results()` is used for **getting results** with `SELECT ...` query. For your task it is better to use `query()` function:

```
$delete_sql = "DELETE from $table_name WHERE id IN ($row_ids)";
$delete_result = $wpdb->query($delete_sql);
var_dump($delete_result);
if($delete_result) {
    $message = count($row_ids) . " submission deleted.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

You should create functions instead of putting all your code together. In different files if possible.

```
<?php
function delete(){
    //your delete function
    //this line will return true at the end 
    return true;
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    if($delete($_POST['delete'])) {
?>
        <div id="message" class="updated notice is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
            <button type="button" class="notice-dismiss">
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss this notice.</span>
            </button>
        </div>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Let me know if it works